# Odoo11 - Display pop up message with a cron task

Tags: python, odoo-11

I created a cron to compare the quantity of product in stock and the minimum quantity in the rules. I would like that every time the quantity in stock is lower than the minimum of the rules it shows me a popup.

When I run the cron automatically it does not display a message or error

Here is my code:

```
@api.model
def to_do(self):
    res_warehouse = self.env['stock.warehouse.orderpoint'].search([])
    for product in res_warehouse:
        quants = self.env['stock.quant'].search([
            ['product_id', '=', product.product_id.id],
            ['location_id', '=', product.location_id.id],
        ]).mapped('quantity')
        if quants:
            view = self.env.ref('stock_limit_alert.cron_wizard')
            view_id = view and view.id or False
            context = dict(self._context or {})
            context['message'] = 'OK'
            context['params'] = {'nom': product.location_id.id}
            if quants[0] <= product.product_min_qty:
                return {
                    'name':'Success',
                    'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
                    'view_type': 'form',
                    'view_mode': 'form',
                    'res_model': 'cron.wizard',
                    'views': [(view.id,'form')],
                    'view_id': view.id,
                    'target': 'new',
                    'context': context
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible like this because cron is running in backend of odoo when cron is running its not effecting your running environment of odoo its working in another environment you can see them in logs but it doesnot make effect of your running environment.